# Distribution of product of independent Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be i.i.d. $\sim N(0,1)$. Then $$\frac{XY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}} \sim N(0,1/4).$$

How can I prove this? I've tried applying the transformation formula, but it hasn't worked out thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=R\cos \Theta,\ Y=R\sin \Theta$, then, since $X\perp Y$, one can show that $R\perp \Theta$ and $R$ is Rayleigh distributed i.e. $p_R(r)=re^{-r^2/2}$ and $\Theta\sim \mathcal{U}(0,2\pi)$. The desired rv can be expressed as $$Z=\frac{R}{2}\sin 2\Theta=R'\sin \Theta'$$ where $R'$ is Rayleigh distributed with variance $1/4$ and $\Theta'\sim \mathcal{U}(0,4\pi]$. Thus, $$P(Z\le z)=1/{4\pi}\int_{0}^{4\pi}P(R'\sin \theta'\le z)d\theta'\\=1/{4\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}P(R'\sin \theta'\le z)d\theta'+1/{4\pi}\int_{2\pi}^{4\pi}P(R'\sin \theta'\le z)d\theta'\\=1/{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}P(R'\sin \theta'\le z)d\theta'=P(Z'\le z)$$ where $Z'=R'\sin \Theta''$ where $\Theta''\sim \mathcal{U}(0,2\pi]$ and $\Theta''\perp R'\implies Z'\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1/4)\implies Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1/4)$